# Image is black when is saved, but when is printed is alright

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save predicted mask from segmentation neural network. When I am trying to save the result, the saved image is black. But when I have used the `cv2.imshow()` function, the image is fine.

My code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

def load_image(img_path, show=False):
   img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(256, 256))
   img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)                    
   img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)         
   img_tensor /= 255.                                      

   return img_tensor

model = load_model('model.h5')
input_image = load_image('input.jpg')

mask = model.predict(input_image)

cv2.imshow("output", mask[0]) #cv2.imshow() is working alright, so mask is correctly printed
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", mask[0]) #saved image is black
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What should I do ?

Comment: your image is probably with values in [0,1]. imshow scales the image automatically, but imwrite with jpeg doesn't. Either save to png (which handle values in [0,1], ora scale the image: mask = mask*255

Comment: Thank you! I have used `mask = mask*255` and it works.